# jQuery cart hover target css class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently building an e-commerce website found here http://www.trade-tools.com . On the right side of the header I have a cart button with the amount as well as items in the cart. When I hover over the cart a popup should show what's in the cart like here http://demo2.woothemes.com/storefront/. I am not able to get this to work. I have the jQuery in my script as "jQuery" and not "$" as I am running it through Wordpress. I believe I am not properly targeting my css classes with jQuery but I can't figure it out. Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

```js
jQuery('.cart-parent').hover(function () {        
    jQuery('.widget_shopping_cart').slideDown(500);
    return false;
});
jQuery('.widget_shopping_cart').mouseleave(function () {        
    jQuery(this).slideUp(500);
    return false;
});
```

```css
.cart-tab .cart-parent {
  position:relative;
}
.cart-tab .widget_shopping_cart {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="right cart-tab light visible">
  <a class="cart-parent">
    <span class="amount">$0.00</span>
    <span class="contents">0 items</span>
  </a>
  <div class="widget woocommerce widget_shopping_cart">
    <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
      <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget">
        <li class="empty">There are no products in your cart.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jQuery is working fine here. It must be something else.

Comment: You're including lots of javascript in the head. Move them to the footer. The jQuery needs to be fired after the HTML has finished loading. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for javascript here, you can do it purely in CSS.... Add the following lines to your css:

`.cart-tab:hover .widget_shopping_cart {
    display: block;
}

.cart-tab {
    position: relative;
}`

Don't include the ` before and after the code, not sure why SO makes me add that.

I tried it inspect view so it should work. If it's not, try making sure the css is placed lower than any that might override it from the default theme styles.

Comment: I really appreciate this solution. I can't believe I didn't take the approach to pure css. Thanks!

Comment: Hah, no problem. I used to do everything in jQuery too because I was not very good at CSS so I just avoided it. I'm slowly learning to embrace the CSS :)